# Selenium loop consume demasiada RAM

Tags: python, bucles, selenium-webdriver, scraping, ram

Estoy con scrapper script el cual tiene un método que recibe una lista de links (aprox 5000), ejecuta un loop y scrapea los datos de cada link:

```
def get_content_info(self, list_data):
    '''Get particular info of each movie'''
    print('Scrapeando ', len(list_data), ' movies.')
    driver = self.selenium_options()
    for data_movie in list_data:
        url = data_movie[0]
        image = data_movie[1]
        try:
            driver.get(url)
        except Exception:
            continue
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
        content = {}
        content['id'] = md5(f'{url}'.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        try:
            content['title'] = soup.find('h1', class_='headline-paused').get_text()
        except AttributeError:
            content['title'] = None
        content['url'] = url
        content['image'] = image
        content['type'] = 'movie'
        content['synopsis'] = self.get_synopsis(soup, url)
        try:
            content['duration'] = soup.find(
                'span', class_='u-separator js-runtimeConvert u-inlineFlexCenter').get_text()
        except AttributeError:
            content['duration'] = None

        self.build_payload(content)
```

La cuestión es que los primeros 30 links los visita correctamente y a partir de ahi empieza a correr cada vez más lento el script, a punto de dejar inutilizable la pc, hasta generar el siguiente error [image: RAM ERROR]

¿A qué puede deberse esto? Me parece muy raro ya que se instancia una sola vez el driver y luego va visitando en una misma ventana los links, aquí mis settings para selenium

```
def selenium_options(self):
    '''Selenium settings'''

    options = FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-application-cache')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'...', options=options)

    return driver
```

Cualquier ayuda para optimizar este método se agradece.

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Significado del error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: out of memory
```

Este error te indica, que `Selenium` le está requiriendo al sistema operativo memoria RAM, y el sistema operativo le ha contestado "ya no me queda más memoria disponible". Es decir has utilizado toda la memoria RAM de tu ordenador.

### 2. Solución

En tu script, haces un `driver.get("xxx")` para crear un navegador que acceda a la web. Incluso con las opciones que pones como `options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')` y otras, aunque dicho navegador no lo veas, obviamente tiene que existir un navegador para acceder a la web y que renderice el contenido, es decir el objeto `driver` consume espacio en tu memoria.

La pregunta es, **¿Cuantos navegadores web puedes abrir en tu ordenador, hasta que este colapse?**, cuantos más habrás, más lento empezará a ir, hasta que no quede nada de espacio y colapse.

**La solución** es una vez has usado el navegador (`driver`) es cerrarlo con `driver.close()`, es decir esta parte del código quedaría así:

```
for data_movie in list_data:
    driver = self.selenium_options() #Creamos un driver cada vez que visitamos una página
    url = data_movie[0]
    image = data_movie[1]
    try:
        driver.get(url)
    except Exception:
        continue
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
    driver.close() #Cerramos el driver una vez tenemos la información
    content = {}
```

### Bonus

Aunque tengas un mismo `driver` este objeto va guardando información de las páginas en las que ha estado, ya que es un navegador y los navegadores hacen eso.

Lo correcto es crear un driver para cada consulta que se quiera hacer y destruirlo una vez tengamos la información.

Comment: Muy clara tu respuesta, se podria realizar un conteo de hasta 30 links, y una vez que se llego se limpian los datos con un driver.quit() y se instancia nuevamente selenium?  porque instanciando en cada for me tarda demasiado :/

Comment: Sí claro, podrías hacer un `batch` con un doble bucle `for` por ejemplo, dividiendo el número de links totales entre 30. También puedes usar la librería `multiprocessing`, pero es algo más complicado, lo que hace es que ejecuta varias terminales de python a la vez y por tanto puedes visitar 5, 8, 10, 20...X páginas a la vez